# Unique Popup cookie name on every page of same website - How to add?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how to add unique cookie name for a popup in every page of the same website, so each page will have its own cookie and I could safely copy & paste the code on to other pages. The issue is - Popup has to appear on all pages, but cookie is browser session based. So it blocks the popup pop on rest of the pages. Is it something related to Page Cookie, if so can someone please explain how and where to add?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var link;

if (getCookie("was_here_before") == "") {
    setTimeout(openPopUp, 3000);
    createCookie("was_here_before", "yes");
}

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;

    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }

    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);

            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }

            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }

    return "";
}

function openPopUp() {
    element = document.getElementById("background");
    element.style.display = "block";
    element = document.getElementById("popup");
    element.style.display = "block";
}

function closePopUp() {
    element = document.getElementById("popup");
    element.style.display = "none";
    element = document.getElementById("background");
    element.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tip: You don't need spaces within HTML tags. ie: `< script >` `< /script >`.

Comment: Can you clarify what your desired behavior is? `"once per session (which ever page, I inserted the popup)"` This sentence doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Okay, I'm still not understanding what the difference between the current behavior and the desired behavior is.  Maybe give a few examples of `action|expected outcome|current behavior` for a couple of example navigation steps.

Comment: Okay, then you either need to use a different cookie for each page, or you need to identify in the cookie value the pages that it shouldn't show up for.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, thanks Waxen, assigned different name for the cookie in every page

Page 1:

```
if (getCookie("was_here_before") == "") {
setTimeout(openPopUp, 3000);
createCookie("was_here_before", "yes");
}
```

Page 2:

```
if (getCookie("was_here_before1") == "") {
setTimeout(openPopUp, 3000);
createCookie("was_here_before1", "yes");
}
```

Page 3:

```
if (getCookie("was_here_before2") == "") {
setTimeout(openPopUp, 3000);
createCookie("was_here_before2", "yes");
}
```